# How to upgrade Git through Chocolatey that I got when installing Cmder

Tags: git, chocolatey, cmder

I installed Cmder by running the following in an Administrative PowerShell:

```
choco install cmder
```

This also installed Git for me. But it installed an older version of Git, not the latest that is listed on the [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/).

The version of Git that got installed is `2.14.3.windows.1` but the latest as of today is `2.16.0.windows`.

How do I tell Chocolatey to upgrade to the latest version of Git? Is that even possible when I did not explicitly install Git via Chocolatey?

I mean I could go and do it manually, but I then thought, what's the point of Chocolatey!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK cmder embeds Git. So you can't update it with Chocolatey.

But cmder is only a bundle of portable software, so you may update Git in the `vendor` subfolder using portable package from https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: hmm, I'm thinking I should've downloaded Cmder without Git, and then install Git separately.

Comment: Actually you may download ConEmu separately